# How to convert time into an integer

Tags: c++, time, int

I have the following code:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

const std::string currentDateTime() {
    time_t     now = time(0);
    struct tm  tstruct;
    char       buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%X", &tstruct);

    return buf;
}

int main() {   
    std::cout << "Current Time is: " << currentDateTime() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this and i get: Current Time is: 18:30:11

I want to know how to convert that into an integer so it appears as just 18.5 or something along those lines. I want to do it because I want to create a timetable.
Example: if its 10:30, I want the program to be able to tell me what subject i have (for school).
Something like this:

```
if(time == 10.5)
    std::cout<<(subject);
```

Any advice on how to do this? I'm fairly new to c++ and I'm not sure if I'm going about this the completely wrong way. Is there another way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `18.5` is not an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you mean converting the time to a **floating point number**. In your `currentDateTime` function you already use `struct tm`. Based on that you could get a `float` hour value by:

```
time_t now = time(0);
struct tm tstruct = *localtime(&now);

float f = tstruct.tm_hour + tstruct.tm_min / 60.0 + tstruct.tm_sec / 3600.0;
cout << f << endl; // prints 10.1025 at 10:06:09
```

Comment: I tried doing that but when I run it, I get this:
19.1711
Current Time is: ├ÉÉÉÉÉ■       È       ■       ║¸┐vÉÉÉÉÉÞ♣ç  ├QìL+╚âß☼♥┴←╔♂┴YÚ1\
  ÉÉÉÉÉï Uïýïà└t☼ü8¦¦  ☼ä♫s♦ ]├ÉÉÉÉÉï Uïýâý$í`↨┼v3┼ëE³SV ïu♀ÞÃ   ïÏë]ÓYà█☼ä╬s☺ W
3 ï¤ïÃëMõ9ÿ►_┼v☼äuì♦ Aâ└0ëMõ=­   rµü¹Þ²  ☼ä¼s☺ ü¹Ú²  ☼äás☺ ☼À├P §lq┼và└☼äÄs☺ ìEÞ
PS §Pq┼và└☼ä‼ì♦ h☺☺  ìF∟WPÞO?  ë^♦â─♀3█ë~♀C9]Þ☼çáî♦ ë3└ì~►☼À╚ï┴┴ß►♂┴½½½VÞ▀  Y3└_
ïM³^3═[ÞéL  ïÕ]├ÉÉÉÉÉï Uïýâý►ìM­j ÞäL  â%╠►┼v ïâ°■☼ä    ï♦ â°²☼ä┴☺  â°³☼ä♀ï♦ Ç}³

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 2.589 s
Press any key to continue.
And the program stops responding,

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to fix it by adding return 0; at the end.